# AnyDVD/RedFox Alternative - Decryptor not Ripper software

Tags: windows, optical-media, drm

I loved AnyDVD because it wasn't a big program designed for "All in one" ripping. It just removed encryption so you can use any program to copy movie. It is no longer working with the latest BluRay and RedFox didn't work with my BluRay Drive.

I'd like a similar program that doesn't rip disks, but just removes encryption. Want it to be small, run in tray and be automatic/ unannoying lol.

Comment: How welcoming, 2 downvotes and not a single comment as to what is wrong. Please see this Meta Post >> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Answer (score 0):

This was infact a QnA style post to give back to this new community I joined. I looked hard for this program.

Its called [DVDFab PassKey](https://www.dvdfab.cn/passkey-lite.htm), be careful of the full "DVDFab" full software if you don't want the "All in one package", the Passkey program is what runs in the background and removes encryption so you can use your software of choice. It worked with the latest BluRay and also my personal disk drive (HL-DT-STBD-RE__WH14NS40_1).

The passkey software runs in the background in tasktray, can be set to autostart or not with windows and auto-decrypts disk with a tiny pop-up in right corner to let you know its working. Great Software!